# Unable to get values from individual check boxes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an asp.net webforms page. I have three html checkboxes and if any of them are checked I have to append the corresponding values to a JavaScript string. When I execute the btnSave, the saveOrderTypes() is called and goes up to alert("D"); and then exits. I don't see any JavaScript error in the console. I am not sure why this is happening. I tried to get the values using jQuery and similar issue happens.

```
<asp:Content ID="scriptArea" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="headerScript">
<script>
function saveOrderTypes() {

        alert("In saveOrderTypes");
        var orderTypes = '';

        if (document.getElementById('chkDelivery').checked) {
            orderTypes = 'D';
            alert("D");
        }
        if (document.getElementById('chkUPS').checked) {
            orderTypes = orderTypes + 'U';
            alert("U");
        }
        if (document.getElementById('chkCustomer').checked) {
            orderTypes = orderTypes + 'C';
            alert("C");
        }
        
        alert("orderTypes: " + orderTypes);
    //more code here
  }
 $(document)
   .ready(function () {

});
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="mainDivision" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
<div class="row" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkDelivery">
        <label >Delivery</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkUPS">
        <label >UPS</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkCustomer">
        <label >Customer</label><br>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
<button type="button"  id="btnSave" onclick="javascript:saveOrderTypes();return false;" 
>Save</button>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Weird. I made a codepen and it worked just fine. Can you remove the onclick and add the click event via addEventListener and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Hi Souleste, I tried that. Still same issue. I am really dumbfounded why this simple code doesn't work.

Comment: Me too. Is this the entire pages markup?